# Laravel - Uploading to a different server via IP address or URL

Tags: laravel

I have 2 servers that are load balanced and I have a 3rd server that is created to house assets that will be shared between the 2 different sites.

I am running Laravel 4.2 and was wondering how to change the uploading of file to go to the file server instead of the hosting server. Is there a way to set it to the server's IP address or URL as the destination of the upload?

Comment: Basically files are uploaded by HTTP Post requests, just change the post URL to the ip (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) or unresolved domain (http://www.yourotherserver.com/uploadhandlingscript.php) of your other server upload handling script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should write your own uploading file service from web server to file server, eg. FTP. Or upload your files to file server directly then notify your web server(callback).